# How to get in Javascript specific Object of iteration done in a Django template

Tags: javascript, django

I have the next iteration in a Django template. This shows me a group of images and their title.

```
    {% for i in blogs %}
        <div class="content__blog">
            <h4 class="content__blog__h4">{{i.title}}</h4>
            <img class="content__blog__img" src="{{i.image.url}}" onclick="clickImage()">
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

What i want to do by adding JavaScript is that when clicking on an Image it'll resize. But only the image clicked.
How do i specify in the JS file which image i'm clicking on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
{% for i in blogs %}
    <div class="content__blog">
         <h4 class="content__blog__h4">{{i.title}}</h4>
         <img class="content__blog__img" id="{{i.id}}" src="{{i.image.url}}" onclick="clickImage(this)">
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

js

```
function clickImage(e){
   // e is image element
   alert(e.id)
}
```